# Android: getting text from layout container

Tags: java, android

A user can create over 20-30 EditTextes and the app must save theirs.

I have a problem: I don't know how can I get text from these EditTextes.

This is my code in xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editext_amount" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText1_price" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code in activity:

```
layout_container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_items);       
 View view_item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_item,layout_container,false);
        layout_container.addView(view_item);

@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view == button_add_item)
        {
            field_count++;
            if(field_count < 50)
            {
                View view_item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shop_item,layout_container,false);
                layout_container.addView(view_item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this...

```
private EditText et1;  

then in the onCreate() function...

et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_text);

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if(view.getId() == R.id.editText_text)
    {
        String str = et1.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Thus String can be got from other EditTexts. Hope it helps.